# How can i configure reverse-proxy server using nginx on centos 7?

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, centos7

I'm trying to construct reverse proxy server using nginx on centos 7.

I installed nginx and also nodejs for local web server.

I would like to redirect requests on nginx to local nodejs server (http://localhost:5000).

So, following this page
www.packethead.net/2015/01/05/setup-nginx-reverse-proxy/

, i modified /etc/nginx/nginx.conf file like below.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name *.example.org; # my domain
    location / {
    proxy_set_header x-real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header x-forwarded-for $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header host $host;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;
   }
}
```

Then, using `systemctl restart nginx.service` command, I restartd nginx.

When i access example.org on browser, just i can see this.

[image]

Is there any special configuration which have to be added?
Is my above configuration file not correct??

I can not even guess what's fault.

I watched many explanation for reverse proxy.

Can you guys recommend easy explanations for me?

Thanks for watch.

Comment: "redirect", or "proxy".  They're two very different things.

Comment: Is your node.js server _listening_ on 127.0.0.1?

Comment: Yes. the server listening on localhost.

Comment: Sorry for misuse. I mean proxy. not redirect.

Answer (score -1):

The proxy did not work because of firewall of centos 7.
 After shutdown the firewall, It have been working^^